# Help to build a basic proof on orthonormal basis in Elementary Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is on Elementary Linear Algebra, by Anton as Theorem 7.1.4. He asks to prove it as an exercise. I think it is something very trivial, as he doesn't bother to show the proof. But I clearly have no idea how to do it and it's quite unnerving that some authors just leave it like this.

Suppose $S = \{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, ..., \mathbf{v}_n\}$  is an orthonormal basis for an $n$-dimensional inner product space $V$, and let $(u)_S = (u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$ and $(v)_S = (v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ be the coordinate representations of vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ in the basis $S$.

(a) The norm of $\mathbf{u}$ is given by:
$$
 \|\mathbf{u}\| = \sqrt{u_1^2 + u_2^2 + \dots + u_n^2} 
$$

(b) The distance between vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is given by:
$$
d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = \sqrt{(u_1 - v_1)^2 + (u_2 - v_2)^2 + \dots + (u_n - v_n)^2}
$$

(c) The inner product of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is given by:
$$
\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \rangle = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + \dots + u_nv_n
$$

Comment: Try to consider a small example, where your orthonormal basis is simply $\{[1, 0]^\top , [0,1]^\top\}$, i.e., the canonical basis. That might help

Comment: Hint: $\mathbf{u}=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mathbf{v}_i$, so $a_i$'s are the coordinates for $\mathbf{u}$ in the basis $\{\mathbf{v}_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Then $$\|\mathbf{u}\|^2=\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u}=\sum_{i,j=1}^na_i a_j \left(\mathbf{v}_i \cdot \mathbf{v}_j \right). $$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is it that you don't understand about this problem? How to express $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ in terms of the $(u_i), (v_i)$ and $\mathbf v_i$? Did the author not discuss this in the chapter? Or do you not understand how the inner product is bi-linear (i.e., $\langle a\mathbf x + b\mathbf y, \mathbf z\rangle = a\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf z\rangle + b\langle \mathbf y, \mathbf z\rangle$ and v. v.)? That the norm is defined by $\|\mathbf u\| = \sqrt{\langle \mathbf u, \mathbf u\rangle}$? That the distance function is defined by $d(\mathbf u, \mathbf v) = \|\mathbf u - \mathbf v\|$?